# Python large floating division

Tags: python, floating-point

I try make division in Python with float number but I am getting incorrect result even I try round float number but it didn't work. Is there other wat how python make division for large float number?

```
>>> div = 1.45751734864e+15/30933
>>> print div
47118525478.9
```

same in java

```
>>> double div = 1.45751734864e+15/30933;
>>> System.out.println(div);
4.711852547893835E10
```

Comment: On my 32 bit system I get: `47118525478.93835` in Python

Comment: Why is that number incorrect? Python shows you a fixed number of digits by default to make the value a little more readable, but that doesn't mean the value itself isn't more precise.

Comment: @jamylak: Older python versions use only the 12 most significant digits in the `repr()` output.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "incorrect result"?

Comment: What's your expected output btw ?

Comment: The correct result should be 4 dot and 47118525478 dot and I can't figure out why Python make division that way..

Comment: What does "4 dot and 47118525478 dot" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Both Python and Java results are **correct** :

**Python**:

```
47118525478.9
```

**Java**

```
4.711852547893835E10
```

**However**, in Java, the number is printed in [exponential notation](http://www.vendian.org/envelope/dir0/exponential_notation.html) format. So, it is equivalent to:

> 4.711852547893835 * 10<sup>^10</sup> = **47118525478.9835**

If you want to print your Python's output as an exponential notation format as well use [String format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) :

```
>>> div = 1.45751734864e+15/30933
>>> print '{:e}'.format(float(div))
4.711853e+10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the precision by using *decimal* module.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 30
>>> Decimal(1.45751734864e+15) / Decimal(30933)
Decimal('47118525478.9383506287783273527')
```

Read: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html and http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 0):

The numbers returned by Python and Java are the same:

IPython using python 2.7.3:

```
In [1]: 1.45751734864e+15/30933
Out[1]: 47118525478.93835

In [2]: 1.45751734864e+15/30933.0
Out[2]: 47118525478.93835

In [3]: 1.45751734864e+15/30933.0-4.711852547893835E10
Out[3]: 0.0
```

Python 3.3:

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Mar 22 2013, 20:14:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.1 ((branches/release_31 156863))] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1.45751734864e+15/30933
47118525478.93835
>>> 1.45751734864e+15/30933-4.711852547893835E10
0.0
>>>
```